# Is there a shortcut key for new objects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

Very often I need to create a new object via a default constructor.  E.G.

`List<string> myList`

I would like to be able to blast some keystroke that setup the rest...

`List<string> myList = new List<string>();`

Any way to do that with Visual Studio 2010 or a DevExpress plugin (DXCore, CodeRush, or Refactor! Pro)?

Comment: You can type `var myList = new List<String>();` and anytime intellisense comes up, just hit Tab to have it insert the selected item.

Comment: Good point.  I haven't been making much use of var like I should...

Comment: Usually by the time I type "new " I can hit tab and complete it. I don't think "n-e-w-[space]-[tab]" is that inconvenient that it would merit a plugin/macro. (Though I do wish that if I used `String` or `Int32` in generic types it wouldn't use the `string` and `int` counter-parts.)

Comment: @Brad I think you're in the minority there; most people seem to prefer the aliases (`int`, `string`, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is VS or R# doing it, but I can use `Li`<kbd>tab</kbd>`st`<kbd>tab</kbd>`myList = n`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and it will complete to that. However, personally I would suggest simpy:

```
var myList = new List<string>();
```

or even `var myList = new Li`<kbd>tab</kbd>`st`<kbd>tab</kbd>`();`

That way there *is* no duplication or anything more to automate.

Comment: Except typing `var myList = new List<String>();` doesn't get you to autocomplete as fast as `List<String> myList = n`[tab][tab]

Comment: All is based on the fact that you've selected those types before and they're fresh on the intelli-sense list, otherwise you get things like `Li` = `LinkedList<T>`, `n` = `namespace`. But now we're getting into pedantics.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a code snippet for this, but the second part is always suggested by Visual Studio.
Another way could be to use var:

```
var myList = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending to a more broader subject.
When you have a very complex object creation (like writing the same boilerplate code for your new classes) take a look at this free utility from codeplex called [Snippet Designer](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/)
Try the shortcut Ctrl+K Ctrl+X.

Answer (score 0):

On Resharper it is for me:

`List<string> myList = new`<kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: I use it very often and can't live without it. Especially not if you have to initialize some Dictionary<K,T>. Btw not sure whether its Resharper or VS itself.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be written really fast if you just use that IntelliSense autocompletes on certain characters such as {}<>() etc.

`li<s>myList=n`<kbd>Space</kbd>`();`

That is 10 keystrokes if we don't count typing out the variable name `myList`.